# Jongo Maven Dependency causing problems

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, intellij-idea, jongo

I am currently trying to use the Jongo project to connect to a remote MongoDB.
To do so, I added these dependencies to my project :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I already had some troubles with the first dependency (jongo:1.0), since maven could not retreive this version (the latest maven knew was 0.4) : Intellij tells me `Dependency "org.jongo:jongo:1.0" not found`. Yet, the dependency can be found [there](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.jongo~jongo~~~~kw,versionexpand)

I managed to get it via `Project Structure -> Librairies`

[image]

The problem is that this dependency is now local, and anyone who clones this project must import this dependency manually, which is not suitable.

I am using Intellij IDEA 13.0

Comment: You can always create a system type dependency and make it point to a directory of your project; then you can simply check in the library into your versioning system as part of your project and everyone will be able to use it without needing to manually set anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the Sonatype dependency version in the snapshots repository you had linked in your post is `1.1-SNAPSHOT` and not `1.0`.

**It's not recommended to use 3rd party snapshots in your build**

If however you insist, you need to add Sonatype snapshots repository to your maven build as follows:

```
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
    <name>sonatype-snapshots</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>        
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

**EDIT**

The `1.0` version resides in Sonatype releases repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-releases</id>
    <name>sonatype-releases</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: [link](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.jongo~jongo~1.0~~)
See there, 1.0 is not a SNAPSHOT, it is present under the Releases repository... However I do agree with you

Comment: @Thibault One more thing, your mongodb-java-driver version is old. Newest version is `2.11.3`

Comment: That one helped too ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Jongo 1.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jongo%7Cjongo%7C1.0%7Cjar) is in maven central.  There is no need for extra repository configuration in your pom.

Comment: Well, I guess the problem came from anywhee else, since I added the dependency that you can see in the first post, and it did not work. I will try to do this on my own computer, but this is odd...